# Is there a word for other fractions analogous to whole, half, quarter?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have been trying to google it for the past half-hour and I cannot come up with anything. I also don't know how to phrase my question properly.

Do we have words for other fractions analogous to
1=whole
1/2=half
1/4=quarter

1/3=?
1/8=?

If there are, I figure they are archaic, but I need to know.

Comment: eighth, sixteenth, thirty-second,...

Comment: ...third, etc. No, they are not archaic.

Comment: Let's try to help with the question: you've noted that a fourth is called a *quarter* and one of two equal pieces is called a *half*, and you're wondering whether a fraction like ⅛ has a special name like *octer* or something? [That's just an example, as far as I know ⅛ is not also called that.] Is that right?

Comment: Yes @AndrewLeach exactly.

Comment: @Drew no. 1/4= fourth, but I'm looking for words like quarter but for 1/8 or 1/5 etc

Comment: No to your no. The words for 1/8th, 1/16th, etc. are just what I said. "A hundredth" or "one hundredth", etc. "Half", "third", "fourth" or "quarter", "fifth",.... And "three quarters" or "three fourths",...

Answer (score 2):

Not in everyday standard English, no. The fractional numbering system has become standardized. *Half*, *third*, and *quarter* are exceptions; otherwise the *-th* suffix is applied to all simple numbers from *fourth* onward ([OED](https://oed.com/view/Entry/200045)).

There may be specialized words that are used to name fractions, but they're more limited. For instance, *tithe* (*teinds* in Scotland) is usually used to denote contributing one-tenth of one's income to a church, and seems odd outside of that context ([OED](https://oed.com/view/Entry/202566)). *Moiety* is used to denote a half, usually in legal uses ([OED](https://oed.com/view/Entry/120752)). If there are other terms, they will likely have similar limits.

Comment: "Third" serves as both the head noun in names of fractions with 3 on the bottom, and as the ordinal 3rd. It is not an exception.